# Overriding the JS focus() method on IE 8 with ASPX and DEVExpress ...

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, devexpress

I have this situation - on our ASPX site, uses DEVExpress, only on IE 8 (the original one, not IE 9 in mode IE 8) on the login page we have constantly an error:

```
Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.
```

And so - I researched and found out that something is trying to focus something that is not visible. So I tried this solution - overriding the focus() method. Here is a short example HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>AccuLynx</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      HTMLInputElement.prototype.focusCpy = HTMLInputElement.prototype.focus;
      HTMLInputElement.prototype.focus = function () {
        if( this.style.display != 'none' && this.style.visibility != 'hidden' && !this.disabled && this.type != 'hidden' ) {
          HTMLInputElement.prototype.focusCpy.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="submit" id="my_link" style="display:none;" value="dfsdfd" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('my_link').focus();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then on the test page everything looks OK, but on the real site - not.

The JS code is one of the first things that is executed - at the beginning of the second JS file (the first one is a JQuery plugin) - but it doesn't work.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I would first try finding the code that issues the focus statement and prevent this from occurring. If this is not possible, you can try handling the error, and if raised setting the focus to an allowable element.

Comment: it is strange issue. it is better to contact DX and ask them for the fix.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution :) ... changed the JS code to this one:

```
  HTMLInputElement.prototype.focusCpy = HTMLInputElement.prototype.focus;
  HTMLInputElement.prototype.focus = function () {
    if( this.style.display != 'none' && this.style.visibility != 'hidden' && !this.disabled && this.type != 'hidden' && this.style.width != '0px' && this.style.width != '0%' && this.style.width != 0 ) {
      HTMLInputElement.prototype.focusCpy.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
```

Or in other words - I added the check for the width of the element, cause after some time I remembered that this ridiculous browser - IE - very often renders some elements with width and height 0px.

And now it works :)

Comment: We had a similar problem with the DevExpress popup controls that was due to a DIV having 0 width. This answer helped us fix the behaviour for IE8.

Comment: Tried this solution, works well in my local machine, but after deploying to the server, I get the error that **'HTMLInputElement' is undefined**. What could be the issue???

Comment: thanks! great solution. It fixed the same issue too on the latest version of devexpress.